# Como fazer uma requisição... XMLHttpRequest com array

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-request, xmlhttprequest, proxy

seguinte código:

```js
let info = new Array()

info[0] = 'index.php'
info[1] = 'portifolio.php'
info[2] = 'nn'

let url = ['https://xraros.000webhostapp.com/']
let proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    for(let i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4){
            if(ajax.status == 200){

                console.log('achou')          

            }else{
                console.log('nao achou')

            }            
        }
    }
    ajax.open('GET',proxy+url+info[i],true);
    ajax.send()
}
```

quero saber por que não aparece no console as outras respostas e só aparece uma que é:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://xraros.000webhostapp.com/nn 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ teste.html:40
teste.html:32 nao achou
```

tem como testar os valores do índice da array e mostrar para cada um se **achou** ou **não achou**?
Faz tempo que estou com essa duvida..., só tentei assim mesmo como está o código acima. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mova o `let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()` para dentro do seu laço *for*. Você deveria criar um objeto para cada iteração, do jeito que você está fazendo, você está cancelando a requisição anterior ao invocar o método `send` no mesmo objeto:

```js
let info = new Array();

info[0] = 'index.php';
info[1] = 'portifolio.php';
info[2] = 'nn';

let url = 'https://xraros.000webhostapp.com/';
let proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                console.log('achou o endereço ' + info[i]);
            } else {
                console.log('nao achou o endereço ' + info[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    ajax.open('GET', proxy + url + info[i], true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo! ajudo muitissimo! =)